# AngularFire pagination and recommended practices by the Firebase team

Tags: angularjs, pagination, firebase, promise, angularfire

I've searched for a clean way to implement infinite scroll pagination using angularfire and I found a rather simple way of doing it.

This morning I've watched the videos about the new version of firebase.
I found [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vDp5LYPFm8Y) explaining that unwrapping promises inside of a controller is an anti-pattern because angular takes care of that for us in it's digest cycle when doing this in the router resolver and injecting this a dependency in the controller.

So I was like... hmmm, is it even possible to implement infinite scrolling using the router resolver instead of doing it inside a controller since it mean making an other query ?

If you had multiple thousands of entries, would you rather do an anti-pattern or load all the data while the user is looking at a spinner for X seconds ?

Well, your thoughts on the question interest me.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

well, you can take at look at this, it'll give you good ideas of how to implement it, maybe you can wrap it within angularFire as a new service, that's what I'm trying to do.

https://github.com/deltaepsilon/firebase-paginator

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CH9ptm4NeTw

the problem of using this library directly is that you have to trigger a digest cycle each time you paginate to update the paginated collection to the view. so I'm looking forward of how to integrate it well by extending the $firebaseArray service.